# Representation of hasOne nad hasMany in sqlite/sequelize

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have defined few tables.

In my db.js file where i connect them i am trying to create 
1:n relation ( has many )
1:1 relation ( hasOne )

to demonstrate with tables

```
var sponzor = sequelize.define('sponzor',{
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull:false,
                primaryKey:true,
                autoIncrement:true
            },
            name:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            lastName:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            number:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
    }) 

var k_osoba = sequelize.define('kontaktna_osoba',{
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull:false,
                primaryKey:true,
                autoIncrement:true
            },
            name:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            }
    })
```

i used

```
db.k_osoba.belongsTo( db.sponzor ); // 1:1
db.sponzor.hasOne( db.k_osoba); // 1:1
```

in k_osoba table it created another row with name "sponzorId" which is foreign key and its correct.

But in sponzor table id did not create foreign key of sponzor.
Why is this happening? I am using sqlitebrowser to see the tables.

The same happens with usage of hasMany.

The tutorial demonstrate the same usage.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#hasone)

> HasOne associations are associations where the foreign key for the one-to-one relation exists on the target model.

And further down :

> Even though it is called a HasOne association, for most 1:1 relations you usually want the BelongsTo association since BelongsTo will add the foreignKey on the source where hasOne will add on the target.

So in your case :

```
db.k_osoba.belongsTo( db.sponzor ); // Adds `sponzorId` to `k_osoba`
db.sponzor.hasOne( db.k_osoba); // Again uses `sponzorId` to `k_osoba`
```

So far with this configuration you will have :

```
db.sponzor.createK_osoba({..}); 
someInstanceOfK_Osoba.getSponzor();
```

Which is probably what you are looking for.

And further :

```
db.k_osoba.hasOne( db.sponzor ); // Adds `k_osobaId` to `sponzor`
```

Which in your case probably you won't need anyway.

Comment: Im quite confused , i do not have much experience with sequelize/sqlite. So by using my code i posted , i can use db.sponzor.createK_osoba() to add kosoba to row in sponzor table and getSponzor() to retrieve sponzor from osoba? Why isnt hasOne displayed in sqlitebrowser while belongsTo is?